# Copying/setting vertex attribute to adjacent vertices in bipartite graph

Tags: r, igraph

I have a bipartite co-authorship network with researchers and their affiliated institutions. The institutions have a vertex attribute denoting their country (in V(sg)$country). I would like to copy this attribute to each researcher connected to the node, so that "a" would have a "country" attribute of "China", and "e" would have "US" in the example below:

[image: link to graph]

Additionally, some of the researchers have moved to institutions in other countries throughout their careers, and are thus connected to several institutions. In cases such as these it would be ideal if they got their attribute from countries that is most often in their neighborhood (e.g.: "c" would get "China" and not "France".

I am very new to coding, and this is my first question here, so I apologize in advance for my noobish ways.

Reproducible example

```
library(igraph)

set.seed(1)
sg<-sample_bipartite(10, 5, p=.3)

countries<-c("US","France","China")
V(sg)[type=="TRUE"]$country<-sample(countries,replace=TRUE,5)

V(sg)[type=="FALSE"]$label <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j")
V(sg)[type=="TRUE"]$label <- V(sg)[type=="TRUE"]$country
V(sg)$color[1:10] <- rgb(0,1,0,.5)
V(sg)$color[11:15] <- rgb(1,0,0,.5)
plot(sg)
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.  Can you be more specific?  Usually, you'll get more/better answers if you ask a small, bounded question -- vague "how do I do this" questions usually don't get answers.

Comment: Perhaps you could just clarify the desired output for this sample input. You want to add a new attribute that all the nodes with `type=="TRUE"` that contains the most common country they are connected to? What happens in the case of a tie (ie `d`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
library(igraph)

set.seed(1)
sg<-sample_bipartite(10, 5, p=.3)

countries<-c("US","France","China")
V(sg)[type=="TRUE"]$country<-sample(countries,replace=TRUE,5)

V(sg)[type=="FALSE"]$label <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j")
V(sg)[type=="TRUE"]$label <- V(sg)[type=="TRUE"]$country
V(sg)$color[1:10] <- rgb(0,1,0,.5)
V(sg)$color[11:15] <- rgb(1,0,0,.5)
plot(sg)


idx <-  V(sg)$type==0
res <- lapply(ego(sg, idx, order = 1), function(x) 
  names(tail(sort(table(V(sg)$country[x[-1]])), 1))
)
V(sg)$country[idx] <- res
unlist(V(sg)$country[V(sg)$label=="a"])
# [1] "China"
unlist(V(sg)$country[V(sg)$label=="e"])
# [1] "US"
unlist(V(sg)$country[V(sg)$label=="c"])
# [1] "China"
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you!